# How to import a Jenkin's Plugin Configuration to another Instance

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Other than installing the plugin in the new Jenkins instance and configuring with the same options, is there another method of migrating/importing plugin configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
After you save Jenkins Settings (in the GUI) once, it will generate xml files for the plugin configurations in `$JENKINSHOME`.

Should have known I was working with docker jenkins.